# why i can't see the resources on AWS EKS, after i created a Cluster through CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, aws-cli, amazon-eks

I created a basic EKS Cluster from CLI, it created all the resources and i could view them through my CLI(pods, nodes, nameservers etc.)

However - when getting into AWS platform i could find the cluster that i've created, but i can't see any resource there.

the EKS command was:

`eksctl create cluster --name demo --region eu-west-1 --node-type t3.micro`

it worked on my friends account, got the same configuration and same IAM role. I've tried to change region, remove the instances type, add permissions, but still i can only see the cluster but no resources(on AWS)

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The user you are logged in as [in the AWS console] probably doesn't have permission to view k8s resources. You need to make sure that the user or role you are accessing the console with is mapped to an RBAC group in the aws-auth ConfigMap. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html for additional information.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I created a cluster using the following command:

```
eksctl create cluster --name <name> --nodes-min=3
```

Then, when I wanted to check in the Aws console, I realized that on the EKS service page I needed to change the region (in my case to eu-north-1).

After this, the cluster was visible.